# How to execute a command in cmake before generation?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake

I want that CMake runs a command before it starts its generating process.

Therefore I add `execute_process` at the very beginning of my *CMakeLists.txt` but the expected prompts are come only sporadic.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg)

execute_process(COMMAND @echo 'HUHU HUHU HUHU')
execute_process(COMMAND pwd)
execute_process(COMMAND make -C ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/msg -f Makefile)

include_directories(include)
add_library(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
    "src/source.cpp"
)
```

Any Ideas?

---

Why I want to do so:

I need to generate a Cpp class from some simple definition files.

1. check if the source of the generator or the definition files newer than the generated class file
2. build generator if needed
3. generate source files
4. build a static library

The points 1 to 3 I have solved with a simple Makefile. 4. is done with a CMakeList.txt because this library ist a subproject in a bigger project.

---

The output to the *CMakeList.txt* from above without my `echo`:

```
Process package 'amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg' with context:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 source_space => /home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
  build_space => /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
install_space => /home/.../install
   make_flags => -j8, -l8
  build_tests => False
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+++ Building 'amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
==> '. /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make cmake_check_build_system' in '/home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
==> '. /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make -j8 -l8' in '/home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/.../src/source.cpp', needed by 'CMakeFiles/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.dir/src/source.cpp.o'. Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:99: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If the makefile were called correctly cmake can find the `source.cpp`. But without the call no source and header exist...

the tree before calling the msgGen

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── msg
│   ├── def1.msg
│   ├── def2.msg
│   ├── def3.msg
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── msgGen.cpp
├── package.xml
└── README.md
```

the tree after calling the msgGen

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── source.h
├── msg
│   ├── def1.msg
│   ├── def2.msg
│   ├── def3.msg
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── msgGen
│   └── msgGen.cpp
├── package.xml
├── README.md
└── src
    └── source.cpp
```

---

adding `RESULT_VARIABLE`

```
alex:overlay_ws$ ament build --only-packages amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
# Topological order
 - amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg

Process package 'amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg' with context:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 source_space => /home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
  build_space => /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
install_space => /home/.../install
   make_flags => -j8, -l8
  build_tests => False
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+++ Building 'amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
==> '. /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make cmake_check_build_system' in '/home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/msg'
make gen
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/msg'
msgGen: build msgGen
g++ msgGen.cpp -o msgGen --std=c++11 -D'GENTARGETCPP="../src/source.cpp"' -D'GENTARGETH="../include/source.h"'
msgGen: run msgGen
dlCpm.msg dlIomReceiver.msg dlIomSender.msg
mkdir -p ../src/
mkdir -p ../include/
./msgGen
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/msg'
msgGen: ready
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/msg'
-- Found ament_cmake: 0.0.0 (/home/alex/git/AMBA/Software/ros2_ws/install/share/ament_cmake/cmake)
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
==> '. /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make -j8 -l8' in '/home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.dir/src/source.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX static library libamba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.a
[100%] Built target amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
+++ Installing 'amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
==> '. /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake__install.sh && /usr/bin/make install' in '/home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
[100%] Built target amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/environment/library_path.sh
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/ament_index/resource_index/package_run_dependencies/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/ament_index/resource_index/parent_prefix_path/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/local_setup.bash
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/local_setup.sh
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/local_setup.zsh
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/ament_index/resource_index/packages/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/ament_cmake_export_include_directories-extras.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/ament_cmake_export_libraries-extras.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsgConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsgConfig-version.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/package.xml
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/register_amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg_implementation.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/get_amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg_typesupport.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/configure_amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg_library.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/include/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
-- Installing: /home/.../install/include/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/source.h
-- Installing: /home/.../install/lib/libamba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.a
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/local_setup.bash
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/local_setup.sh
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/local_setup.zsh
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/setup.bash
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/setup.sh
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/setup.zsh
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/_order_packages.py
```

removing *src* and *include* dir

```
alex:overlay_ws$ ament build --only-packages amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
# Topological order
 - amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg

Process package 'amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg' with context:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 source_space => /home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
  build_space => /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
install_space => /home/.../install
   make_flags => -j8, -l8
  build_tests => False
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+++ Building 'amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
==> '. /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make cmake_check_build_system' in '/home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
==> '. /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make -j8 -l8' in '/home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/src/source.cpp', needed by 'CMakeFiles/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.dir/src/source.cpp.o'. Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:99: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

<== Command '. /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make -j8 -l8' failed in '/home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg' with exit code '2'
<== Command '. /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make -j8 -l8' failed in '/home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg' with exit code '2'
```

changing to `ERROR_VARIABLE`

```
alex:overlay_ws$ ament build --only-packages amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
# Topological order
 - amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg

Process package 'amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg' with context:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 source_space => /home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
  build_space => /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
install_space => /home/.../install
   make_flags => -j8, -l8
  build_tests => False
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+++ Building 'amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
==> '. /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make cmake_check_build_system' in '/home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/msg'
make gen
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/msg'
msgGen: build msgGen
g++ msgGen.cpp -o msgGen --std=c++11 -D'GENTARGETCPP="../src/source.cpp"' -D'GENTARGETH="../include/source.h"'
msgGen: run msgGen
dlCpm.msg dlIomReceiver.msg dlIomSender.msg
mkdir -p ../src/
mkdir -p ../include/
./msgGen
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/msg'
msgGen: ready
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/.../src/amba_ctrl/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/msg'
-- Found ament_cmake: 0.0.0 (/home/alex/git/AMBA/Software/ros2_ws/install/share/ament_cmake/cmake)
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
==> '. /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake__build.sh && /usr/bin/make -j8 -l8' in '/home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.dir/src/source.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX static library libamba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.a
[100%] Built target amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
+++ Installing 'amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
==> '. /home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake__install.sh && /usr/bin/make install' in '/home/.../build/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg'
[100%] Built target amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/environment/library_path.sh
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/ament_index/resource_index/package_run_dependencies/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/ament_index/resource_index/parent_prefix_path/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/local_setup.bash
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/local_setup.sh
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/local_setup.zsh
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/ament_index/resource_index/packages/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/ament_cmake_export_include_directories-extras.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/ament_cmake_export_libraries-extras.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsgConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsgConfig-version.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/package.xml
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/register_amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg_implementation.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/get_amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg_typesupport.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/share/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/cmake/configure_amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg_library.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/.../install/include/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg
-- Installing: /home/.../install/include/amba_ctrl_datalinkmsg/source.h
-- Installing: /home/.../install/lib/libamba_ctrl_datalinkmsg.a
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/local_setup.bash
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/local_setup.sh
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/local_setup.zsh
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/setup.bash
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/setup.sh
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/setup.zsh
-- [ament] Deploying: /home/.../install/_order_packages.py
alex:overlay_ws$
```

Comment: `execute_process()` happens during the Configuration phase, which is before the Generation phase. What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: I want to run a source code generation. This generates the source for the target in this CMakelist.txt

Comment: Then I run cmake 'huhu...' never printed to the terminal. Also the print outs of my Makefile are not visible. If I run manually make with the command above I can see the outputs.

Comment: I'm sorry but that still doesn't explain what happened. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Add your CMake errors to your question. Maybe the directory structure of your project. Your question is probably fairly easy to answer, but we do need more details.

Comment: You won't see HUHU... on the terminal because `@echo` is an error. CMake is not the same as `make`. You want to use `echo` instead of `@echo`.

Comment: Check result of your *COMMAND*s via *RESULT_VARIABLE* option, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5302811/3440745).

Comment: Read the documentation for [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/execute_process.html). Particularly, the bits about `OUTPUT_VARIABLE` and `ERROR_VARIABLE`)

Comment: Define _"the expected prompts are come only sporadic"_. What, **exactly**, do you see?

Comment: OK - If I run this with one of these variables it will work one time. After deletion of *src* and *include* dir the cmake runs into an error until I change to an other kind of variable...

Comment: Based on your `CMakeLists.txt` you never call `msgGen`, all you do is build it. If `msgGen` is supposed to build `src/source.cpp`, then of course you'll get a "file not found" error from CMake.

Comment: Ok - I found out, that my last described behaviour is only due to CMake doesn't call my Makefile if CMake don't have any detected change on *CMakeList.txt* or target dependencies or the target themselves. It seems that `execute_process` isn't called prior checking the dependencies.

Comment: Maybe I shall split it up into two projects depending on each other. Is it possible to force cmake to check against non source files?

Comment: `It seems that 'execute_process' isn't called prior checking the dependencies.` - 'execute_process' is run as a part of **configuration process** (`cmake` call), there is **no dependency checking** at this stage. BUT: if you call `make` on *already configured project*, re-configuration takes a place only when `CMakeLists.txt` is changed.

Comment: Hm - so my approach seems not to be a good one. Is there a other handy way you can suggest to me?

Comment: Why do not use common `add_custom_target`/`add_custom_command ` approach for generate source files? E.g. `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/source.cpp COMMAND make -C ...)`, `add_custom_target(generate DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/source.cpp)`, `add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} generate)`.

Comment: YES the last advice leads to success. Please write an answer which I can check as solution! Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev and the others. Here is the way I choose:

*CMakeList.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(datalinkmsg)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/DatalinkMsg.cpp
                   COMMAND make -C ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/msg -f Makefile)

add_custom_target( generate
                   ALL make -C ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/msg -f Makefile
                   DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/DatalinkMsg.cpp
                   DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/msg/msgGen.cpp
                   DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/msg/*.msg )
...
```

this runs with the corresponding *msg/Makefile*

```
MSGDEFS = *.msg

TARGET = msgGen
SOURCE = msgGen.cpp

GENTARGETCPP = ../src/DatalinkMsg.cpp
GENTARGETH   = ../include/DatalinkMsg.h

all: $(GENTARGETCPP) $(GENTARGETH) $(MSGDEFS) $(SOURCE)

$(GENTARGETCPP): $(MSGDEFS) $(SOURCE)
    make gen

$(GENTARGETH): $(MSGDEFS) $(SOURCE)
    make gen

gen: $(TARGET) $(MSGDEFS) $(SOURCE)
    mkdir -p ../src/
    mkdir -p ../include/
    ./$<

$(TARGET): msgGen.cpp
    g++ $< -o $@ --std=c++11

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(GENTARGETCPP) $(GENTARGETH)
```